# Rendered component test fails after Ember 1.10 upgrade

Tags: ember.js, ember-qunit

I'm unit testing a component, in particular the rendered form. I'm approaching this pretty much [as described in the Ember Guides](http://emberjs.com/guides/testing/testing-components/).

In particular, the component has three computed properties which show different classes on the rendered elements depending on the backing model. I'm tweaking the properties in `Ember.run()` blocks and then looking at the rendered component again.

What's interesting here is that the computed properties seem not to be re-computing even through I'm touching the attribute they observe. Later tests which *don't* test rendering - just the return from the component - do pass.

Here's my test code:

```
moduleForComponent('wizard-tab', "Component - WizardTab", {
  setup: function () {
    this.tab = this.subject({ step: 2, stepCompleted: 1, tab: tabs.all()[1] });
  }
});

test('#render', function () {
  let tab = this.tab;
  ok(this.$().find('span.wizard-tab-detail').length, "Active tab has a detail span"); // Passes
  // Note that both of the additional states observe stepCompleted
  // so I need to touch that to get them to recalculate
  Ember.run( function () {
    tab.set('stepCompleted', 2);
    tab.set('tab', WizardTab.all()[4]);
  });

  ok(this.$().find('span.wizard-tab-icon-disabled').length, "Future tabs have a disabled class"); // Fails

  Ember.run( function () {
    tab.set('stepCompleted', 3);
    tab.set('tab', WizardTab.all()[1]);
  });

  ok(this.$().find('span.wizard-tab-icon-done').length, "Inactive tabs have a done class"); // Fails
});
```

The first assertion passes, the next two fail. Using `console.log` statements I've validated that the `set()`s are working, but the property calculated from them is returning the wrong result.

Here's one of the computed property definitions:

```
  disabled: function() {
    return this.get('tab.stepNumber') > (this.get('stepCompleted') + 1);
  }.property('stepCompleted')
```

(I literally get `false` for `5 > 2` when I put in `console.log` checks on that comparison.) **Is there something I'm missing that would prevent that from updating when I check subsequent renders of the component?**

This is ember CLI 0.2.0, Ember 1.10.0 and ember-cli-qunit 0.3.8.

**ETA:** Probably relevant: this test passes on Ember 1.8 and ember-cli-qunit 0.3.1. It's the update to Ember CLI 0.2.0 and accompanying Ember and ember-cli-qunit updates which cause the failure.

(**ETA:** note from kiwiupover's comment below that this section below isn't relevant to the problem; the guides may not show the best current way to do this.)

Note that the guides use a similar pattern:

```
test('changing colors', function() {

  // this.subject() is available because we used moduleForComponent
  var component = this.subject();

  // we wrap this with Ember.run because it is an async function
  Ember.run(function() {
    component.set('name','red');
  });

  // first call to $() renders the component.
  equal(this.$().attr('style'), 'color: red;');

  // another async function, so we need to wrap it with Ember.run
  Ember.run(function() {
    component.set('name', 'green');
  });

  equal(this.$().attr('style'), 'color: green;');
});
```

I tried wrapping the second and third assertions in `andThen()` but that raised errors - `andThen()` was undefined.

Comment: I just posted the some question to the ember-mocha repo https://github.com/switchfly/ember-mocha/issues/25 and as you can see the response by @rwjblue the docs are incorrect. I just haven't had time to update them.

Comment: That explains why `andThen` doesn't work, thanks. Still not sure why the tests fail without them, though it sounds now like following the guides example closely is not the most reliable way of building a test.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got this working by starting a new branch off development (our default branch) and re-running the update. Here are the differences between my original pass and what worked:

- More component updates, I think just because some time has passed since my first attempt. `ember-resolver`, `loader.js`, `ember-cli-app-version` and `ember-cli-dependency-checker` had all moved up. I don't know if any of those mattered, but they did change.
- The key part, I think, was isolating the three tests in separate test blocks *and also* updating the subject in an `Ember.run()` block for each test that used different attribute values from the setup component.

Here's what the three tests looked like when they passed:

```
moduleForComponent('wizard-tab', "Component - WizardTab", {
  setup: function () {
    this.tab = this.subject({ step: 2, stepCompleted: 1, tab: WizardTab.all()[1] });
  }
});

test('Rendered active tabs have a detail span', function () {
  let tab = this.tab;
  ok(this.$().find('span.wizard-tab-detail').length, "Active tab has a detail span");
});

test('Rendered future tabs have a disabled class', function () {
  let tab = this.tab;
  Ember.run( function () {
    tab.set('step', 2);
    tab.set('stepCompleted', 2);
    tab.set('tab', WizardTab.all()[4]);
  });
  ok(this.$().find('span.wizard-tab-icon-disabled').length, "Future tabs have a disabled class");
});

test('Rendered inactive tabs have a done class', function () {
  let tab = this.tab;
  Ember.run( function () {
    tab.set('step', 2);
    tab.set('stepCompleted', 3);
    tab.set('tab', WizardTab.all()[1]);
  });
  ok(this.$().find('span.wizard-tab-icon-done').length, "Inactive tabs have a done class");
});
```

I believe that last change - moving from one test with some `Ember.run()` blocks to three - is what really did it. I used some `{{log value}}` lines in the template to look at which values were being sent to the template, and it was using the subject from the `setup` block all three times until I added the `Ember.run()` blocks.